# Drupal 6 storing files in non-relative to install path location and accessing via a different subdomain

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I've searched around about this, but I can't find a clean solution.  I'd like to develop a module for Drupal 6 that will allow me to have the **/sites/default/files** directory configured so:

- File uploads are uploaded to a folder on the server that IS NOT a path relative to the drupal install path
- Links are accessed publicly via a different or sub-domain

I'm assuming I need to hook several [File interface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/group/file/6) functions including [file_directory_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_directory_path/6) and [file_create_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_create_url/6), though I'm unsure of which functions to hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to use a absolute path (instead of the default relative one) in the file system settings at admin/settings/file-system.

Displaying a different link might be more complicated, not sure how to do that in D6. I'd suggest having a look at http://drupal.org/project/cdn or a similar module to see what they're doing.

Comment: CDN patches core, there is no other way and so it's a good idea to steal the patch from there :)

Comment: hmmm, so core patching is the only way.  You know off hand if D7 has a non-hack solution?

Comment: Very likely, yes. In Drupal 7, the whole file handling was rewritten using streams, you access files with public://somefile.jpg or private://somefile.jpg, can define your own handlers which Drupal should use (s3:// to automatically push files to Amazon S3 would be an example) and you can multiple of these on the same site (public/private/... is a per-field setting, not global)